# Save the changed language on app with Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have this code, are two buttons, one for spanish and other for english, just i use another class which is "Language Helper", to change language, and when its done i reload the activity:

```
btn_es.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LanguageHelper a = new LanguageHelper();
            a.cambiarInt(0);
            b = 0;
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("language", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("key", b);
            editor.apply();
            LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getResources(), b);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            Animatoo.animateShrink(CMF_Settings.this);
        }
    });
    btn_en.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LanguageHelper a = new LanguageHelper();
            a.cambiarInt(1);
            b = 1;
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("language", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("key", b);
            editor.apply();
            LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getResources(), b);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            Animatoo.animateFade(CMF_Settings.this);
        }
    });
```

Two buttons change the language, and this class:

```
public class LanguageHelper {
int key = 0;

public static void changeLocale(Resources res, int locale) {
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

    switch (locale) {
        case 0:
            config.locale = new Locale("es");
            break;
        case 1:
            config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
            break;
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void cambiarInt(int i){
    key = i;
}
}
```

So with that i can change the language in all aplication, but when i close and started again, i use this code to load the saved language:

```
    public void LoadInt() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("language", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int b2 = sp.getInt("key", b);
    if(b2==0){
        LanguageHelper a = new LanguageHelper();
        a.cambiarInt(0);
        LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getResources(), b2);
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        Animatoo.animateFade(Settings.this);
    }else{
        LanguageHelper a = new LanguageHelper();
        a.cambiarInt(1);
        LanguageHelper.changeLocale(getResources(), b2);
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        Animatoo.animateFade(Settings.this);
    }
}
```

but doesn't load. So there's another easily way to change and save? or what i need more?

Comment: At what point do you call `LoadInt()`?

Comment: In , "on crate" after of  "setContentView"